# Validation of percentage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i can't seems to validate the percentage.
Need you guys help me to solve!

```
 function validate()
    {
       s
   if( document.myForm.outputPercentage.value <= 0||>=100

   {
     alert( "Please the correct percentage." );
     document.myForm.outputPercentage.focus() ;
     return false;



<form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return(validate());">

Last output percentage: <input type"text" name="outputPercentage" id="outputPercentage" />&<br/><br/>


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Is the `s` just a typo ?

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Also, you have to check each condition, like this `if (something <= 0 || something >= 100)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Also, form element `value`'s are strings, not numbers.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara so i should change the value to?

Comment: You should cast it to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected your code so that it works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var outputPercentageString = document.myForm.outputPercentage.value;
            var outputPercentage = parseInt(outputPercentageString);
            if (outputPercentage <= 0 || outputPercentage >= 100) {
                alert("Please the correct percentage.");
                document.myForm.outputPercentage.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return(validate());">

        Last output percentage: <input type="text" name="outputPercentage" id="outputPercentage" />%
        <br/><br/>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

1. Remove the 's' all on its own.
2. Everything on a web page is a String, so to compare the percentage to a number you have to use parseInt to make it into a number.
3. `type"text"` should be `type="text"`
4. if you open a bracket `{` then you must close it afterwards `}`
5. Put the javascript into `<script>` tags in the `<head>` element of the page
6. I've put everything into `<html>` elements.
7. Learn what getElementById() does. Everybody uses ids to get references to webpage elements rather than names.

Hope this helps.